# How to unarchive a git repository archive created with $ git archive

Tags: git

I have some git archives created using the `$ git archive` tool.

Any idea how to restore these archives into repositories?

Comment: Only to avoid misunderstandings: it's not possible to recover the Git history from this archive as it's not packaged in the archive.

Answer (score 5):

`git archive` doesn't archive your repository. It creates a tarball archive of *one particular revision* inside your repository. So you can't take the output of `git archive` and turn it into a full repository it came from, sorry.

You can extract the single revision that a `git archive` generated tarball contains with `tar xf <filename>`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what the value of the --format option was, you can extract them using the appropriate tool, i.e. unzip for format=zip, tar for format=tar, gzip/tar for format=tgz, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Zip it up:**

```
# git archive --format zip --output filename.zip my_branch
```

**Zip it out:**

```
# unzip filename.zip
```

### Update:

**Set your origin and checkout into branch:**

```
# git checkout -b my_branch origin/my_branch
```

Comment: Yeah more or less. This gives you the contents of the .git folder. In order to turn it into a working repo I ended up having to move the contents of the unzip into a .git folder, then check that out to get a working tree.

Answer (score -1):

Take 2.

**Solution:**

I am the author of this project:
https://unzipgit.github.io

**Explanation:**

Github does not provide an option to unpack the archive in the repository, but there is a solution. The problem can be solved using the Github API (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents). Their API allows you to upload files to the repository. Of course, if we send an archive, the archive will be uploaded, but if we parse the archive and loop through it, we can send each file to its own repository.

In my personal experience I have encountered this problem. It turned out that the solution has been waiting since the very creation of Github. As it usually happens, rather than waiting for a large company to implement something, it is easier to do it yourself.

If we're talking about JavaScript, we can get the contents of a ZIP archive using JSZip (https://stuk.github.io/jszip/). To my surprise, a very handy library (special thanks for the choice of file reading mode). If we simplify it very much, then uploading an archive looks like this:

```
// reading the archive
zipFile = await zip.loadAsync(inputArchive, { binary: true });
// loop
for (const [p,f] of Object.entries(zipFile.files)) {
  // read as base64
  base64file = await f.async("base64");
  // upload to github
  await reqest("PUT",`${url}/${fileName}`,{content: base64file});
}
```

You can implement this yourself or use my solution that I made for myself.
The logic is the same as I have already said. For convenience, I implemented the ability to send an archive from your computer or select an archive that is already in the repository.  In both cases, the browser will load the archive and traverse it, sending each file to the repository.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The person's goal: unzip the archive into github repositories. I suggest using a service that I made for myself. All this is said in the reply. I have nothing more to add